# How do we make fractions flip?

Tags: derivatives, fractions

Title might not be approriate but I am not sure how to ask this. I have a question asking to find the error rate and in one of the steps, the fraction flips. I suspect it's because we are trying to make denominators the same, but I really have no clue.

**Question**: We want to estimate the relative error $dg/g$ using the relative error for time $dt/t$.

This is the supplied information;

$g = \frac{10}{t^2}$

and

$\frac{dg}{dt}=-\frac{20}{t^3}$

The provided equation is: $\frac{dg}{g}=\frac{1}{g}\cdot \frac{dg}{dt}\cdot dt$

The next step is: $\frac{t^2}{10}\cdot \left(-\frac{20}{t^3}\right)\cdot dt$

So how or why did g ($\frac{10}{t^2}$) change to $\frac{t^2}{10}$?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{~\frac{a}{b}~}=\dfrac{b}{a}$... so $\dfrac{1}{g} = \dfrac{1}{~\frac{10}{t^2}~}=\dfrac{t^2}{10}$

Comment: If you need a proof of this... then note that $\dfrac{1}{~\frac{a}{b}~}=\dfrac{1}{~\frac{a}{b}~}\times 1 = \dfrac{1}{~\frac{a}{b}~}\times \dfrac{b}{b}=\dfrac{b}{~\frac{a}{b}\times b~} = \dfrac{b}{a}$

Comment: Thank you so much JMoravitz! I knew it was something like that, I just couldn't figure it out. haha so simple. If you just make this into an answer, I will mark it as solved